# Proxy Server context timeout

Tags: go, http, connection-timeout

I am trying to test the HttpServer code.I have mocked my proxy calls in the code
Here's my server code:

```
func HttpServer(t *testing.T,version string,test ReqRes, basePath string, timeout int,transport metrics.HttpInstrumenter, corsConfig middleware.CorsConfig) (*http.Response,[]byte, bool){
    proxyAuthServer := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(test.proxyAuthStatusCode)
        _, err := w.Write([]byte(test.proxyAuthResp))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }))

    defer proxyAuthServer.Close()

    configs :=config.Config{
        Outbounds: struct {
            APIAuthentication struct {
                AuthPath    string `yaml:"authPath"`
                AuthTimeout int    `yaml:"authTimeout"`
            } `yaml:"apiauthentication"`
            
        },
    }


    var mockProxy proxy.Proxies
    newproxy:=proxy.NewProxies(zap.NewNop(),proxyInstrumenter,proxyTransport)
    mockProxy,_=newproxy.Make(configs,proxyAuthServer.URL,"")

    proxyAuthServer.URL=proxyAuthServer.URL+configs.Outbounds.APIAuthentication.AuthPath


    service:=base.NewService(proxy.Proxies{ApiAuthenticationService:mockProxy.ApiAuthenticationService,OfferPrefixDataService:mockProxy.OfferPrefixDataService},true) 
    service=base.NewLoggingMiddleware(zap.NewNop())(service)
    service = base.NewInstrumentingService(instrumenter)(service)


    //Generating req
    resp,_:=http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    body,_:=io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    return resp,body,false

}
```

Here's the line which is calling the proxy and giving error.s implements my AuthProxy:

```
endpointResp, err := s.ValidateEndpoint(ctx, req)
```

Whenever my code makes a proxy call,the proxyAuthServer is returning error like this in my debugger:

**endpointResp: interface {} nil**

error(*net/url.Error): *{Op: "Get", URL: "http://127.0.0.1:58807/auth", Err: error(context.deadlineExceededError) {}}

Why is my proxyAuthServer not returning the response when i have configured my endpoint to the proxyAuthServerURL and maxTimeout to be AuthTimeout.Can somebody explain

Comment: What value did you set `maxTimeout` at `AuthTimeout` in Client? It seems no problem in your code.

Comment: I think the case like you can happen only when the timeout is too small.
I did a tiny experiment at The Go Playground https://go.dev/play/p/u1luHPFsXS2

Comment: yes changing the timeouts of my server resolved the issue.Initially they were too small so my server was timing out

Comment: Thumbs-up! Good luck for your programming~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed that the cause is related to timeout setting.

I think timeout/deadline can happen from two things at the view of client assuming its server has no problem.

1. Req with deadline context. (https://gist.github.com/orian/b54ce2b1cc3a4144b090eb5714725a43)
2. Client timeout (https://medium.com/@jac_ln/how-to-test-real-request-timeout-in-golang-with-httptest-dbc72ea23d1a)

Your problem is not about the deadline. So I guessed it is about 2.

We can test it easily by this code.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "This is only for test")
    }))

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", server.URL, nil)

    client := http.Client{Timeout: time.Nanosecond}
    _, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    return
}
```